# Como coloco un link a URL en menu de bootstrap?

Tags: bootstrap, url, menú, enlace

Quiero poner un link a Facebook que se abra fuera de sitio web pero no funciona, solo cuando se colapsa para version de teléfono funciona. No se mucho de bootstrap. Gracias.

```
    <!-- Sub Page Menu section -->
  <nav class="main-nav">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-toggle"></a>
                    <ul id="sub-nav" class="nav">

                        <li><a href="#about" class="nav-link">Nosotros</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#menu5" class="nav-link">Servicios</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#testimonials" class="nav-link">Experiencias</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#filtergallery" class="nav-link">Portafolio</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#contactform" class="nav-link">Contacto</a></li>
                        <li> <a href="https://www.facebook.com/lacocoyodotcom/" target="_blank" class="nav-link">facebook</a></li>
                        </ul>
                  </nav>
```

Comment: ¿Como que no? Es decir no se te abre el link?

Comment: Hola, no se abre, debería abrirse en otro tab

Comment: Como no sea que no se abra porque el navegador esté bloqueando la ventana emergente, no veo cuál es el problema

Comment: El código funciona correctamente, haz echo pruebas en otros navegadores?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hice una prueba con tu código y no se abre la nueva pestaña como indicas, seguro debe de haber un evento atado a esos links, es decir ya debe de existir un evento asociado que evita que se ejecute el abrir una nueva ventana o pestaña, yo lo solvente creándole un evento solo a los links donde su atributo **href** comience con http así:

```js
$("#sub-nav a[href^='http']").on('click', function (e) {
  let href = $(this).attr("href");
  window.open("https://www.facebook.com/lacocoyodotcom/", '_blank');
  
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

<nav class="main-nav">
  <a href="#" class="nav-toggle"></a>
  <ul id="sub-nav" class="nav">

      <li><a href="#about" class="nav-link">Nosotros</a></li>
      <li><a href="#menu5" class="nav-link">Servicios</a></li>
      <li><a href="#testimonials" class="nav-link">Experiencias</a></li>
      <li><a href="#filtergallery" class="nav-link">Portafolio</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contactform" class="nav-link">Contacto</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/lacocoyodotcom/" class="nav-link">facebook</a></li>
      </ul>
</nav>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Aquí no funciona con este editor, por eso para verlo funcionar puedes verlo [aquí](https://jsfiddle.net/dmolina101/f8m1jgco/).

Espero te funcione.

Answer (score 1):

Hazlo por javascript

```
    <!-- Sub Page Menu section -->
  <nav class="main-nav">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-toggle"></a>
                    <ul id="sub-nav" class="nav">

                        <li><a href="#about" class="nav-link">Nosotros</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#menu5" class="nav-link">Servicios</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#testimonials" class="nav-link">Experiencias</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#filtergallery" class="nav-link">Portafolio</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#contactform" class="nav-link">Contacto</a></li>
                        <li> <a onclick="window.open('https://www.facebook.com/lacocoyodotcom/','_blank')" class="nav-link">facebook</a></li>
                        </ul>
                  </nav>
```

Comment: Esta funciono muy bien...te lo agradezco....recibe un cordial saludo.